# When I host my website I can acess homepage but I always get 404 error when I try to acess my secondary pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost

I'm doing a website, and now I hosted it in a free host service just to do some tests.

And I'm having a problem that I don't have in localhost.

The problem is: I can access my homepage successfully, but whenever I try to access a secondary page I get a 404 error "http://error404.000webhost.com/? ".

I don't see why I'm getting this error, in localhost everything works perfectly, so I will put below my code that I think that can be related to this issue.

Any help will be very welcome.

**My Home() function** that I call in my index.php file with my query string:

```
function Home(){
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = explode('/', $url);
$url[0] = ($url[0] == NULL ? 'index' : $url[0]);

if(file_exists('inc/'.$url[0].'.php')){
    require_once('inc/'.$url[0].'.php');
}
elseif(file_exists($url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php')){
    require_once($url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php');
}
elseif(file_exists($url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
    require_once($url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
}

else{
    require_once('inc/404.php');
}
}
```

**My htaccess file:**

```
  RewriteBase / (we need to use this in 1st htaccess line in the host Im testing)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

**How I acess my secundary pages:** (In this case my teachers/documents secundary page)

```
<li class="item_menu">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);">Teachers</span></a>
     <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="<?php echo BASE;?>/teachers/documents">&nbsp;Documents</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

**My BASE variable:**

In localhost: define('BASE', 'htp://localhost/website');

When I host my project in a host service:`define('BASE','http://myhostexample.org');`

Comment: May be you have an issue in .htaccess file,try to remove all of it's contents,because it has a contents of the localhost .htaccess that causes a problem.

Comment: See http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=16 for their documentation on how to make the RewriteRules match. Also you're likely opening your host up for remote code inclusion by using unvetted input with filesystem functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I update my question with your tip mario, but even doing what documentation says, I got the same issue.

Comment: Why its duplicated? I dont see any question as mine, and Im really trying to understand what is happening!

Comment: It's a continuation of your own/previous question. If that answer didn't solve it, well, don't mark it as answered. -- Next up: check `error.log` and have the `RewriteLog` enabled if unversed. Else `FallbackResource` for Apache 2.4 setups. Your `BASE` variable is not used / what's the relevancy then?

Comment: Its not a continuation of my previous question mario. My previous was about dont allow users to acess my website folders. And BASE variable is always used in my menu items links...